# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'ioredis'

Tags: javascript, nestjs, tsconfig, ioredis

I have a project with nestJS. But in when trying to add some module it show error.

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'ioredis'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'ioredis'
```

and this is my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./",   
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["src/core/*"],
            "@main/*": ["src/main/*"],
            "@migrations/*": ["src/migrations/*"],
            "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"]
        },
        "incremental": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", "dist"
    ]
}
```

How to resolve the error ?

Comment: What is your version of `ioredis`? It should come with types ready to use

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're on `ioredis@4`, it comes without built-in TypeScript definitions. You'll have to install `@types/ioredis`:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/ioredis@4.28.10
```

If you're on `ioredis@5` and use `@nestjs/bull`, the `bull` package [does not support](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/2353) `ioredis@5`. You'll have to downgrade `ioredis`:

```bash
npm install --save ioredis@4.28.5
npm install --save-dev @types/ioredis@4.28.10
```

Update: `bull` supports `ioredis@5` since 4.10.2.

Comment: Saved me couple of hours. Thanks.